# Slot machine program in python

Tags: python

I need my program to return the sum of money spent and the sum of the prizes won at the end of the program after user enters 'N' to stop playing, but in my example it is only returning the last values entered.

```
import random


def calculate_winnings(winning_combos):

    spend = float(input("Enter money to bet: "))
    total_spent = []
    total_spent.append(spend)
    total_prize = []
    
    print(winning_combos)

    #calculate user winnings

    if winning_combos[0] == winning_combos[1] and winning_combos[1] == winning_combos[2]:
        prize = spend * 3
        total_prize.append(prize)
        print(f'You got three matches and you won $ {prize}')
    elif winning_combos[0] == winning_combos[1] or winning_combos[1] == winning_combos[2] or winning_combos[0] == winning_combos[2]:
        prize = spend * 2
        total_prize.append(prize)
        print(f'You got two matches and you won $ {prize}')
    else: 
        print(f'You did not win. Prize is $0') 
    
    play = input(f'WWWWould you like to play? Enter Y for yes and N for no: ').upper()
    while play == 'Y':
        calculate_winnings(winning_combos)
    if play == 'N':
        print(f'total spent {sum(total_spent)} and total won {sum(total_prize)}')
        print('end game.')

#loop through game as many times as user wants

def main():

    # slot machine values
    
    slot_machine_values = ['Cherry', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Bell', 'Melon', 'Bar']
    winning_combos = []
    #calculate random values from above list
    for x in range(3):
        winning_value = random.choice(slot_machine_values)
        winning_combos.append(winning_value)
    
    calculate_winnings(winning_combos)


main()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome.  I suggest you show the output you have to help people answer faster (without having to copy-paste your code and run in their machine).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `calculate_winnings` is recursive but it reset the values of sum won and lost each time:

```
def calculate_winnings(winning_combos):

    spend = float(input("Enter money to bet: "))
    total_spent = []
    total_spent.append(spend)
    total_prize = []
```

It would be better to:

- User integers instead of lists for `total_spent`, `total_prize` (unless you really need the history)
- have `total_spent` and `total_prize` as arguments of `calculate_winnings`

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

```html
import random
import time

slot_val = ["X", "O", "W", "L"]
cslot_val = [] #The current value on screen



def Match(arr): #Comapares all the element in the array to the first element
    for e in arr:
        if e != arr[0]:
            return False
    return True

#print(Match([9, 9, 9, 9, 9])) Test1 True
#print(Match([9, 9, 7, 9, 9])) Test2 False

bet = input("how much do u bet?")

time.sleep(1)
print("Rolling...")

for i in range(3):
    cslot_val.append(random.choice(slot_val))

print(cslot_val)

if Match(cslot_val):
    print(f"YOU WIN ${bet*2}!!!")
else:
    print(f":( You lost ${bet}.")
```

Comment: For my program I need to add up all the money the user spent and all the money they won and display that to them after they decide to stop playing...

Comment: Doesn't look like Python

Comment: @TanishqBanyal it is python :/

Comment: Hi @AloyPro . It is usually recommended to put text and explanations, along with code. Also, usually functions in Python are in lowercase => `match` (and not "Match") ... and this function could be written as `return all(e == arr[0] for e in arr)`